# rails devise set variable to localization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, devise

Pls, help!

How I can change "Devise" localization, if I should set variable to message?

For example:
message

```
signed_up_but_unconfirmed: "A message with a confirmation link has been sent to your email address."
```

I should change to:

```
signed_up_but_unconfirmed: "Check your mail, we’ve sent a confirmation to: %{email}"
```

Where I should to define the variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I decided this problem:

> /config/routes.rb

```
devise_for :users
```

have changed to

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}
```

create:

> /app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb
>   with

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    ......... my code with localization variables
  end

  def edit
    super
  end
.................
end
```

This is my solution!